# How to set trigger if string is already exist in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

For example, I'm trying to create a trigger which is if there are already exists a string in table then insert data values to old existing value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON PARTS
WHEN NEW.Part_name IN(SELECT Part_name FROM PARTS)
BEGIN
...
...
...
END;
```

This will work if Part_name type is integer. But I'm asking how can I work this trigger if Part_name type is String?

Comment: Are you attempting to translate from oracle (when is not an option in mysql or sqlserver) or is this wrongly tagged?

Comment: It is just an example. The point is How can I compare string in a table like: where part_name = select part_name from PARTS .... or something else. So, how can I compare string if string is exist in table then do something (IN MYSQL)

Comment: 'This will work if Part_name type is integer. But I'm asking how can I work this trigger if Part_name type is String?' Should also work if string why do you think it wouldn't and do you have such an example?

Comment: I tried and I got error. I think IN() doesn't work with string. Because I had never see example with string

Comment: WHEN NEW.Part_name IN(SELECT Part_name FROM PARTS) Also this statement is not an option in mysql. Is there a way I can do in mysql?

Comment: @K.tas . . . `IN` works with strings.  Your code would have some other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you would probably want to use if exists. For example

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER t 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON PARTS
for each row

BEGIN
   if exists (SELECT Part_name FROM PARTS where part_name = new.part_name) then
      ##do stuff
   end if;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I tried then I got this error:    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL 
    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
    right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    if exists (SELECT Part_name FROM PARTS where part_name = 
    new.part_name) th' at line 4

Comment: Oops missed for each row clause.

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Do you have any idea for this error: mysql>  insert into PARTS(Part_name,amount,Storage_ID) values('barley',1000,1);
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'PARTS' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: that is my stuff after 'if' condition UPDATE PARTS SET amount=amount+NEW.amount WHERE Part_name=NEW.Part_name;

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger.you can set the New. values

Comment: Okey. Thank you